# Need a third party software that can open .mdi files

Tags: software-rec, microsoft-office-2003

As the topic, I would need something that can open .mdi files. I tried Microsoft Office Picture Manager and Picture and Fax viewer but no luck. Only .tif files can be opened.

Comment: Not sure on third party software, but the official application is Microsoft Office Document Imaging  (Office 2007+) to open the files.

Comment: I have Office 2003

Comment: Pretty sure it's included in Office 2003 as well, not 2007 only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official page about [Microsoft Document Imaging Format (MDI)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/about-microsoft-document-imaging-format-mdi-HP006219360.aspx) states that MDI files can only be opened or edited in **Office Document Imaging**. If you have this utility but can't open .mdi files with it, try the resolutions given in the following Microsoft article:

[KB 926198:](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926198/en-us) "An .mdi file does not open in the Microsoft Office Document Imaging program that is included in the 2007 Office programs"

Alternatively, a quick Google search brings a 3rd party program which is a free tool that can view .mdi files: [MDI Viewer 1.0.32](http://www.downloadatoz.com/internet_directory/mdi-viewer/)